# How to efficiently aggregate an array when calling promise APIs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise

I want to execute a series of getData functions, but only if there is data to get. I then need to compile all the results into a paired value array to return.

The following code works, but I need to do similar for another 7 lots of 'if (card.x)...'
 What is a better way to do it?

```
async function buildingCard(card) {
    let cardToCreate = []
    try {
        if (card.joke1) {
            // wixData.get returns a promise
            let joke = await wixData.get("jokes", card.joke1).then((results) => {
                cardToCreate.push({ "titleText1": results.title })
            })
        }
        if (card.quote1) {
            let quote = await wixData.get("quotes", card.quote1).then((results) => {
                cardToCreate.push({ "fancyText1": results.title })
            })
        }
        return cardToCreate

    } catch (error) {
        console.log("buildcard error: " + error);
        return error;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to do the `get` operations in parallel (all overlapping each other) or in series (one after the other)?

Comment: Also, do the names of the properties on the result object vary like that? You have `titleText1` in the first case, `fancyText1` in the second.

Comment: I've changed your question title to accurately reflect the question. The word 'compile' has a specific meaning in programming that is not applicable here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three things that vary there:

- The name of the property you're checking
- The string you pass `get`
- The result property on the object (this last seems odd)

You can define an array of objects with the values for those, like this:

```
let props = [
    {name: "joke1", key: "jokes", resultKey: "titleText1"},
    {name: "quote1", key: "quotes", resultKey: "fancyText1"},
    // ...
];
```

then if you want to query those in parallel, you can use `Promise.all` to wait for multiple promises to settle, then push the entries from the resulting array:

```
async function buildingCard(card) {
    // Define the stuff you'll do
    let props = [
        {name: "joke1", key: "jokes", resultKey: "titleText1"},
        {name: "quote1", key: "quotes", resultKey: "fancyText1"},
        // ...
    ];
    let cardToCreate = [];
    try {
        return Promise.all(props
            // Only the ones with values
            .filter(({name}) => card[name])
            // Map to the object to push
            .map(
                ({name, key, resultKey}) =>
                wixData.get(key).then(results => ({[resultKey]: results}))
            )
        );
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("buildcard error: " + error);
        return error;
    }
}
```

If you want to do one call at a time, you can use a `for-of` loop instead:

```
async function buildingCard(card) {
    // Define the stuff you'll do
    let props = [
        {name: "joke1", key: "jokes", resultKey: "titleText1"},
        {name: "quote1", key: "quotes", resultKey: "fancyText1"},
        // ...
    ];
    try {
        let cardToCreate = [];
        for (const {name, key, resultKey} of props) {
            if (card[name]) {
                const results = await wixData.get(key);
                cardToCreate.push({[resultKey]: results});
            }
        }
        return cardToCreate;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("buildcard error: " + error);
        return error;
    }
}
```

Comment: in the parallel code `...await Promise.all(properties'` I think this should be `...await Promise.all(props`
also what does the `...` before `await` do? Many thanks

Comment: @mrpowergage - Yes, you're right, that was an editing mistake. In a function call argument list or an array literal, `...` just before an array [*spreads out*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the array entries as discrete arguments / entries. But I realized when fixing the `props`/`properties` thing that there's no reason to create an empty array and then push the results of awaiting `Promise.all` into it; you can just return the result from `Promise.all` directly. I've edited that. :-)

Comment: thanks. I've made a couple of tweeks for my situation, and so wixData received the 2 properties it was expecting. But I'm get an empty result sent back. Any ideas / how do I console log / debug to see whats going on (I'm not confident of where I am within the arrow functions to put in logs)?

Comment: tweak made:
`.map(
        // these changes made to props also
                ({key, collection, resultKey}) =>
                wixData.get(collection, key).then(results => ({[resultKey]: results}))`